# Template argument 1 is invalid with deque

Tags: c++, stl

i am getting the below error when i try to compile the following code below.
please suggest a good fix for the issue'.

> ./DataSecurity.h:60: error: template argument 1 is invalid
>   ./DataSecurity.h:60: error: template argument 2 is invalid
>   ./DataSecurity.h:60: error: expected unqualified-id before â>â token.

```
template<typename E, typename C = std::basic_string<E> >
struct CDsTableRec {
  typedef C CStr;
  typedef Ids::Type::CCountedPointer<CDsTableRec> CPtr;

  CStr    m_table;
  CStr    m_alias;
  CStr    m_prefix;
  CDsTableRec(const CStr& t, const CStr& a, const CStr& p) : m_table(t),       m_alias(a), m_prefix(p) {}
  CDsTableRec(const CStr& t) : m_table(t) {}
  CDsTableRec() {}

  CStr str() const {
    return m_prefix + (m_alias.size() ? m_alias : m_table);
  }
};
```

`typedef std::deque<CDsTableRec::CPtr> > CTableList;` --- this line gives error

`CCountedPointer` is also a template

`Ids` and `Type` are namespaces

Answer (score 1):

1. `CDsTableRec` is a template, you need to provide a template argument to it.
2. There is a `>` to many on that line.
3. `CDsTableRec<X>::CPtr` is a dependent name so you need a `typename` in there as well. (See ["Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords))

So a complete and possibly working declaration would look something like

```
typedef std::deque<typename CDsTableRec<X>::CPtr> CTableList;
```

Where `X` is e.g. `int` or a class/structure name or any other valid type.

If the `CTableList` *also* needs to be a template, you can't use `typedef`, it's not possible to create templated type-aliases using `typedef`. Instead you need to use the `using` keyword to declare a template type alias:

```
template<typename T>
using CTableList = std::deque<typename CDsTableRec<T>::CPtr>;
```

Do note that this is introduced in the C++11 standard. If you have an older compiler that doesn't support C++11 (or higher standard) then you have to rethink your design.

Comment: Hi Joachim Pileborg,  Thank you so much for your quick response. it was helped me a lot, thank you once again